# opencv camera extrinsics (matchmoving)

Tags: opencv

I have questions regarding the cvDecomposeProjectionMatrix function.
The returned translation vector is x,y,z,w. The w is not 1 or 0, so I divide x,y,z by w to get standardized x,y,z coordinates for world space. But the coordinates then jump all over the place with great inaacuracy, despite the fact that the tracking features have a high degree of accuracy between frames.

The euler angles also return incorrect. Though they return the correct corresponding axis of roation for the frames, it over rotates. For example rotating the camera a total of 45 degrees along the x-axis over-n-seconds yields 360 degrees of rotation from the decompose matrix.

What is the most accurate way of using decomposeprojectionmatrix?

Detailed Info:

A professor at Stanford wrote a nice sample bit of code using opencv to calculate opticalflow.

You can find it at the end of the pdf located on Stanford's website. I would include the code but the comments make it a little lengthy for a forum post. http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b05/notes/CS%20223-B%20T1%20stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf

I have built off of that sample, and can track features acuurately in a variety of video formats, but estimating camera position and rotation from those features has proved a big headache.